# Combination of textfields and checkboxes in a custom form

Tags: 7, forms

I need to create a custom form that contains a list of checkboxes and textfields next to each other, as in:

[image]

There are many meal items in the list. Right now I'm using something like:

```
$form[$meal_type->sku] = array (
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('container-inline')), 
  );
  $form[$meal_type->sku]['meal'] = array (
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => $meal_type->title,
    '#return_value' => $meal_type->sku,
  );
  $form[$meal_type->sku]['quantity'] = array (
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => 1,
    '#size' => 5,

  );
```

This creates an individual fieldset for each meal item and quantity.  I just wanted to see if there are any suggestions for a better approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a `'#type' => 'container'` instead of `fieldset`. And I used `#prefix` and `#suffix` in the children to add specific classes for spans and horizontal alignment etc.

One other thing that seemed useful but I ended up not using: template files for form theming. This is a very useful tutorial:

http://themery.com/dgd7/advanced-theming/forms/with-templates